# KeyError when using QString

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qstring, keyerror

I want to execute hash algorithm. So, I made this code. I also imported hashlib. But, in the last line, an error happened:

```
KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'sha1')
```

I don't know what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow)
    self.radioLabel = 'sha256'  #default 256
    self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.OnRadiogroup)

def OnRadiogroup(self,radioLabel)
    self.radioLabel = radioLabel
    self.radioLabel = self.combo.currentText() #get selected hash string

def create_matchkey(self, row, path, key, radioLabel):

    hash_function = {"sha1":hashlib.sha1,
                     "sha224":hashlib.sha224,
                     "sha256":hashlib.sha256,
                     "sha512":hashlib.sha512,
                     "md5":hashlib.md5}
    hash_object = hash_function[radioLabel](self.input_str)
```

Comment: you must provide a [mcve], that is, I can copy your code and run it without problems, but your example is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `QString` from the `radioLabel` into a python string:

```
hash_object = hash_function[str(radioLabel)](self.input_str)
```